# JProgressBar does not update within the loop

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I am currently self-studying Java. I've been trying different things like `JRadioButton`s, `JcomboBox`es etc. Now, I'm trying to use `JProgressBar`s but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Relevant piece of code:

```
JProgressBar progress;
JButton button;     //Fields of the class

progress=new JProgressBar(JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL,0,100);
button=new JButton("Done");    //Done from methods

progress.setValue(0);
progress.setStringPainted(true);
progress.setBorderPainted(true);  //Also done from methods

button.addActionListener(this);   //Also done from methods
```

When `button` is clicked, I want to show the JProgressBar go from 0% to 100%. Here is the relevant portion of the `actionPerformed` method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

        for(int i=0;i<=progress.getMaximum();i++)
        {
            progress.setValue(i);
            /*try{
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
                System.err.println("An error occured:"+ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }*/
        }


        progress.setValue(progress.getMinimum());
}
```

I've added both `progress` and `button` into a JPanel and the panel into a JFrame on which I use `setVisible(true);`.

The problem here is, whenever I press the JButton `button`, the JProgressBar `progress` does not go from 0% to 100%. Instead, nothing happens. If I uncomment the `try...catch` block, and then press `button`, the program "freezes" for a moment and then continues. This time too, The JProgressBar stays at 0% and I never see it moving. I've also tried a `repaint();` just after the `try...catch` block but the same thing happened.

I've tried adding

```
System.out.println(i+"");
```

inside the `for` loop in `actionPerformed` and this printed numbers 0 to 100 in the terminal. So, I'm sure that the loop runs.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Swing is single threaded,
- all updates must be done on EDT,
- all events in current EDT are painted in GUI in one moment,
- `Thread.sleep` to lock execution of event in EDT, repaint can be painted at the end of for_loop, after all lock(s) from `Thread.sleep` are executed, more in Oracle trail - [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [EventDispatchThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

---

output from AWT (Swing) Listener - `ActionListener`, should be done if all events inside `actionPerformed` are executed, then there is executed only `progress.setValue(progress.getMinimum());`, doesn't matter if is there `Thread.sleep` or not

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) -> progress.setValue(progress.getMinimum());
```

---

- use `SwingWorker` or `Runnable#Thread` with `progress.setValue(i);` wrapped into `invokeLater`
- for better help sooner post an `SSCCE`/`MCVE`, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Could you modify my `actionPerformed` method so that I get the expected results? It is difficult for me to go through many online tutorials and find out how to do it.

Comment: you have to redirect whatever that notify JProgressBar to the Workers  Thread, I'd be starting with SwingWorker, e.g. [java+swing+swingworker+jprogressbar](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+[swing]+swingworker+jprogressbar)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put following piece of code to new thread

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

    for(int i=0;i<=progress.getMaximum();i++)
    {
        progress.setValue(i);
        /*try{
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("An error occured:"+ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }


    progress.setValue(progress.getMinimum());
}
```

Something like this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            for(int i=0;i<=progress.getMaximum();i++)
            {
                progress.setValue(i);
                try{
                    sleep(10);
                }catch(InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    System.err.println("An error occured:"+ex);
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
    progress.setValue(progress.getMinimum());
}
```

Not tested, `progress` instance should be `final` maybe

Comment: Swing components are not thread safe and should never be updated outside the of the context of the EDT. Consider using a SwingWorker instead

Comment: This works. But I've read that swing is not thread safe. Also, I want the JProgressBar to go to 100% and After this, the user can use other components. I guess I need `join()` or something like that?(BTW, I'm not very familiar with threading in java)

Answer (score 1):

As far as your code goes, it all looks legit. Doesn't seem to give any issue regardless of not initiating a thread.

What I suggest you do is remove this:

```
//for testing purposes
progress.setValue(progress.getMinimum());
```

And then make the value of the progress bar 50. Remove the thread code, and use the for loop with the condition "< 50".

If all else fails, this will surely shed some light: [JProgress Bar: Working!](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_jprogressbar.htm)

Let me know of the outcome.

Comment: I want to reset the value of the JProgressBar to zero after the loop. In my actual code, there is work to be done between the loop and `progress.setValue(progress.getMinimum())`.

Comment: Yes I understand that. It is required, I suggested it in terms of testing :)